# User Authentication on the SAP cloud platform for the business users on different sap systems which are not connected to SAP cloud

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, user-management, sap-cloud-platform

My SAP Cloud platform is connected to the system called X, but not all the users are available on system X, there are few on Y and some Z as well. So I get the information of all the users from system X, but there is no way that I can get the information from Y and Z. As system X is a normal development system and not the gateway system, we dont have all the users on it.

I have a Fiori application which has users across the systems, but the OData is developed on system X. For SAP cloud platform X is the backend. The reason for this development is we have a consolidated and processed data of all the users on system X by virtue of a custom tool. Now all the relevant data is fetched using the user id, but unfortunately, we don't have all the users in the system X.

Please suggest how to handle this scenario in SAP cloud environment or in the OData itself.

Comment: Additional info - we have a dedicated gateway system with all users info , which is not connected to sAP cloud platform , but is there any way we can make use of this system ?